# Slider dots - css3 to skew them diagonally

Tags: jquery, css, swiper.js

[image]

Is there a css3 way of dynamically making the slider dots skew in a diagonal plane?

https://jsfiddle.net/9dtgqw95/5/

```css
span {
  background: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
span:nth-child(n) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

---

if the container was rotated -- will have positioning problems if there are more dots

[image]

Comment: what about rotate the whole container https://jsfiddle.net/9dtgqw95/6/ ?

Comment: that is an idea -- I suppose - I was trying to see another way of twisting the dots round

Comment: @DaniP - it is close - but then may have issues if there are more dots -- that bottom:20px etc..

Comment: so what is the behavior you want if there is too much dots?

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like what you really want is a [d3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js) app. Might try tagging this question with `d3`

Answer (score 0):

you can push it with position absolute

```css
div {position:relative;}
span {
  background: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: -- lets try a test with multiple different dots -- to see if the solution is universal

Comment: Well you can make as manny nth child's you want. Nothing bad happens if they dont get used :)

Comment: I mean -- if you had multiple sliders -- with different number of dots -- your absolute bottom may not fulfil it

Comment: Thats why i said imagine the absolute max number of items in your slider lets say 10 than you just make 15 nth childs XD

Comment: -- I am talking about if you had x sliders - which as such contain y number of slides -- in a way you want them to be absolutely positioned from the bottom - maybe text-aligned right

Comment: With classes you can narrow the usage down so you just need one time css for all your sliders. Positioning absolute doesnt make a difference because the dots are positioned to the div not the body tag so you can move the div where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can skew the container and skew the dots in the opposite way

```css
div {
    transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;

}

span {
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
  background: red;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

span:nth-child(n) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```